# surjectivity of operators on $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can anyone give me an example of an operator $T:\ell^\infty\rightarrow\ell^\infty$ which has dense range but is not surjective?

Comment: I assume you require $T$ to be continuous and linear?

Comment: The same question was asked on MO and deemed nontrivial by Bill Johnson http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101253/

Comment: Seems that the OP was the one to ask it on MO as well.

Comment: This was originally posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101253/surjectivity-of-operators-on-linfty

Comment: @ellinfinity: Because you do not have 50 reputation points yet, [you can only comment on your own questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757). So, the "add comment" button will only appear for you once you gain 50 points.

Comment: @ZevChonoles I don't understand; how has ellinfinity's comment appeared, then?

Comment: @YemonChoi: Mods have the power to turn answers into comments.